# ASP JSON library

Tags: json, asp-classic

I'm useing JSON2.asp for classic asp support for parsing JSON.
the string i'm getting from the server is something like that

```
{'title':['aaa',0,'1',''],'columns':['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd']}
```

the asp json parser won't work with apostrophe. if i change it to quotation mark it works.
my problem is that the strings might have apostrophe in it (it's in hebrew so a word like: g'irafa is needed.

is there a way to change the json library to support that or to change the string that way that begining of a word will be " or end and not in the middle?

in addition the word can end with ' so if i have 2 at the end just the last one need to be changed.

maybe with regex?

Comment: Is the fact that you have an error in your json a possible explanation for the problem you{re having? `{'title':['aaa',0,'1'], 'columns':['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']}` - double check the quotes

Comment: i have just fixed that... :-) that is not the problem... i just typed it incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

What if you escape the special characters like apostrophes and such? You could run a js or asp function to escape apostrophes (by adding a backslash) to the string, like this: `g\'rafa`

Comment: but then i will get the apostrophe of holding the string to be escaped as well... 'g'rafa' will be \'g\'rafa\' while it need to be 'g\'rafa' or the best "g'rafa"

Comment: I assume you're extracting the data in the json from a database, in which case you can escape the characters in the string *before* inserting them into the json.